# Linearizing SOS1

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, integer-programming

Guys, I am trying to find ways of linearizing the operator Special Ordered Set Type 1 (SOS1). In order to understand what is my goal, I will, firstly, describe the problem I am facing. Let's consider the below mathematical program.

$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}$ $f(x)$

s.t. $h(x) = 0$

$l \leqslant x \leqslant u$

Where $f(x)$, and $h(x)$ are smooth and $\mathcal{C}^1$ vector-based functions.
The lagrangean function of the above program, would be:

$\mathcal{L}(x, \pi, \lambda, \beta) = f(x) + \pi g(x) + \lambda (l - x) + \beta (x - u)$.

Resulting in the below multi-objective program:

$\max_{\pi, \lambda \geqslant 0, \beta \geqslant 0}$ $\min_{x \mathbb{R}^n} \mathcal{L}(x, \pi, \lambda, \beta)$

Which the optimal solution would satisfy the following optimality conditions:

$\nabla_{x} \mathcal{L} = \nabla_x f + \pi \nabla_x h - \lambda + \beta = 0$

$\nabla_{\pi} \mathcal{L} = h(x) = 0$

$\nabla_{\lambda} \mathcal{L} = l - x \leqslant 0$

$\nabla_{\beta} \mathcal{L} = x - u \leqslant 0$

$x^T \nabla_{x} \mathcal{L} = 0$

$\pi^T \nabla_{\pi} \mathcal{L} = 0$

$\lambda^T \nabla_{\lambda} \mathcal{L} = 0$

$\beta^T \nabla_{\beta} \mathcal{L} = 0$

$\lambda, \beta \geqslant 0$

If we desire to linearize the complementarity (or orthogonality) constraints of $\lambda$ and $\beta$, we would  have to impose some constraints conotating that:

$\lambda = 0 \vee l - x = 0$

$\beta = 0 \vee x - u = 0$

For this porpuse, I know that there are SOS1 approaches based techniques, cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403074/define-appropriate-big-m-in-linearize-kkt-complementary-slackness-conditions), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034796/sos1-for-linearizing-complementarity-condition), but AFAIK, SOS1 is based on branching rules, cf. [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/do-solvers-use-gub-sos1-branching), and [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=sos-example-type-1-sizing-warehouse). My question is, is there any way of linearizing SOS1, or simply orthogonality constraints for bounds, without relying on imposing branching rules?

Thanks for the attention, case there is any error or missing point in my statement, please, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $\lambda \ge 0,$ $$\lambda = 0 \vee l - x = 0$$ can be linearized as $$\lambda \le M z$$ $$L (1-z) \le l - x \le U (1-z)$$ where $z$ is a new binary variable and $M, L, U$ are suitably large positive constants.

Comment: Thank you very much @prubin. I appreciate. However, the imposition of an integer variable, already imposes a nonlinearity, although I haven't explicited the desire of conotating SOS1 functionality as a linear expression. Btw, I think that SOS1 implementations also impose integer variables behind the hood. I was thinking in using CG-cuts for this purpose, but I am still thinking about it (First page of karthik.ise.illinois.edu/courses/ie511/lectures-sp-21/lecture-23.pdf). Thank you very much.

Comment: Good luck. The SOS1 constraint makes the feasible region nonconvex, so using linear cuts means you are dealing with an outer approximation of the original problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right, notice this just recently. Regards.